# What is the best way to apply an arithmetic expression to 2 binary numbers provided by the user in C?

Tags: c, math, binary

I am writing a program that accepts 2 binary numbers from the user. Then the user selects a arithmetic expression (+ - / * %) to apply to the numbers. I have the general input code but am at a loss as to where to go next. I'm fairly new to the C language. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int number1, number2;
char expression;

//Basic instructions at the beginning of the program
printf("This is a program to execute arithmetic in binary.\n");
printf("The program will ask you for input in the form of two binary numbers separated byan arithmetic expression (+ - / * %).\n");
printf("The binary numbers must be only 1's and 0's and a maximum of seven digits.\n");
printf("You may exit the program by typing 'exit'.\n");

//Obviously an incomplete do statement, need a loop
do  {
//Getting input from the user
    printf("\nEnter first binary number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number1);
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number2);
    printf("Which expression would you like (+ - / * %): ");
    scanf("%c", &expression);   
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps get a compilable example first. And then do a "switch" on "expression".

Comment: Note the comment that says "Obviously an incomplete do statement". I'm aware its not able to compile.

Comment: %d inputs a decimal number.  To input a binary number you will need to input a string (or character array if pure C) and then parse the string character by character interpreting the string as a binary number.  Then once you have the binary value stored in an int you can use a case statement to evaluate operation being input and performing that operation.

Comment: BTW, it's called *operator*, not *expression*. An *expressions* is the entire formula - for example `1+2` is an expression. The operator is just the `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `expression` is a `char`(and not `char[]`), you can use `switch`-`case`:

```
int result;
switch(expression){
    case '+':
        result=number1+number2;
        break;
    case '-':
        result=number1-number2;
        break;
    case '*':
        result=number1*number2;
        break;
    case '/':
        result=number1/number2;
        break;
}
```

You might also want to add a `default`, in case the user entered an invalid operator.

Comment: Yes, but this is only half the solution - it will **not** give the desired result until the "decimal coded binary" is converted to a true binary representation - and possibly back again depending on the desired output.

Comment: What is the best way to do so? I'm fairly new and would like it explained a little to me so I'm not just receiving information and throwing it into the code.